# await in for-of loop vs fetching the iterable before for-of

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperledger-fabric

See the two code blocks below:

```
for await (const {key, value} of ctx.stub.getStateByRange(startKey, endKey)) {}
```

and

```
let allCarsRangeIterator = await ctx.stub.getStateByRange(startKey, endKey);
for (const {key, value} of allCarsRangeIterator ) {}
```

When I use the first one, everything works, but when I use the second one, I get an error saying allCarsRangeIterator is not iterable.

Why are these two not equivalent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this to be a very interesting question and dug around for a bit. Let's see if I can answer this properly:

First, we need to be clear about [iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators), so I encourage everyone to go through the linked documentation.

The following seems to be a generator:

```js
ctx.stub.getStateByRange(startKey, endKey)
```

As per the docs, a generator is a special type of iterator that can be iterated over only once. On top of that, it seems to be a generator that does some async computation. Let's mock this with a simpler function:

```js
async function* foo() {
  yield 1;
  yield new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 2));
  yield 3;
}
```

As per the docs, in order for an object to be iterable, it needs to implement the `Symbol.asyncIterator` (async) or `Symbol.iterator` (sync) protocol. Let's check this:

```js
async function* foo() {
  yield 1;
  yield new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 2));
  yield 3;
}

(async function () {
  const obj1 = foo();
  console.log(typeof obj1[Symbol.iterator] === "function"); // false
  console.log(typeof obj1[Symbol.asyncIterator] === "function"); // true
})();
```

Now let's see the output if we use `await`.

```js
async function* foo() {
  yield 1;
  yield new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 2));
  yield 3;
}

(async function () {
  const obj1 = await foo();
  console.log(typeof obj1[Symbol.iterator] === "function"); // false
  console.log(typeof obj1[Symbol.asyncIterator] === "function"); // true
})();
```

It's still the same. This conforms to the error you got: `allCarsRangeIterator is not iterable`, because `obj1` does not implement the `Symbol.iterator` protocol but rather the `Symbol.asyncIterator` protocol.

So, when you are trying to use `for (const num of await foo())`, it is a synchronous code, so it is going to look for `Symbol.iterator` protocol implementation. But since your function is an async generator, it only has `Symbol.asyncIterator` protocol implemented.

The only way to iterate over an async generator is therefore:

```js
for await (const num of foo()) {
    console.log(num);
}
```

You will also see that this is valid (although it looks weird)

```js
for await (const num of await foo()) {
    console.log(num);
}
```

Since `(const num of await foo())` still has the `Symbol.asyncIterator` protocol implemented.

---

In fact, in VSCode, you will see a warning whenever you type `for (const num of await foo())`:

`Type 'AsyncGenerator<any, void, unknown>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator. ts(2488)`

and `const obj1 = await foo()` shows the warning:

`'await' has no effect on the type of this expression. ts(80007)`

---

Additional resources:

1. [`for...await of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)
2. [`iterable` and `iterator` protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_async_iterator_and_async_iterable_protocols)